# How Tkinter could load png images with transparent backgrounds?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Some weeks ago i load a png image into my Tkinter Canvas and drawed with create_image, but now i can't do this anymore, i tried convert with ImageTk but png did not display

I have the following code:

```
load = Image.open("mouse.png")
self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
self.draw.create_image(100,100,image=self.img,anchor = NW)
self.draw.image = self.img
```

I just need to present a png image

Comment: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        vSmallIco = (15, 15)
        self.original = Image.open('.//data//img//plus.png')
        resized = self.original.resize(vSmallIco, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.plusIco = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
        self.medIco = ttk.Label(self.mf, image=self.plusIco, style='Main.TLabel')
```

this is done with this import

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Also, please use a *.png image if you wish to use png.

Comment: Sorry, i put the code that worked, but i continue with the problem, it seems Tkinter Canvas reads only gif, pgm or ppm, in many places i read that ImageTk cold solve the problem, but nothing happens to me.

Comment: @PedroOrtiz Your version of Tk could be outdated. Upgrade to the latest version of Python could fix that.